# Trying to find out what format data is in

Tags: php, json, format

looking to find out what format this data is in. I thought it was JSON, but after trying `json_decode()` on it, nada happened.

Data in question:

https://www.habbo.com/gamedata/furnidata/aaba20347c4f45c1e1818e06a3daea617999c2c4

Comment: These are only array of values, keys are not present keys are fixed and defined any other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a `plain/text` format consisting of json arrays, separated by line breaks.

You could do

```
$lines = file('https://www.habbo.com/gamedata/furnidata/aaba20347c4f45c1e1818e06a3daea617999c2c4');
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    var_dump(json_decode($line));
}
```

Comment: Perfect that seems to do the job